# Calculating derivative

Tags: calculus

In order to solve a mathematical problem I have to calculate the following derivative:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta k}\frac{11 + \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1}i}{k}$

Does anyone know this derivative?

Comment: Unless you correct some typos (?), I'm afraid that nobody knows.

Comment: @HandeBruijn corrected:)

Comment: Can you obtain a closed formula for $\sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} j$ ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn there is indeed a closed formule for this but I can't dementer which one that was, something like $\frac{k\cdot(k+1)}{2}$?

Comment: Oh well, I would have lead you to the solution step by step, but someone gives the complete answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(k):=\frac{11+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i}h=\frac{11+\frac{(k-1)k}2}k=\frac{22+k^2-k}{2k}=\frac k2-\frac12+\frac{11}k\implies$$

$$f'(k)=\frac12-\frac{11}{k^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your expression can be written as:
$$\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{22+k^2-k}{k}\right)=\frac{-22+k^2}{2k^2}$$.